# Google sheets Java API read formula not calculated value

Tags: java, google-sheets-api

I am using the Google Sheets Java API to pull data from a spreadsheet, like so:

```
ValueRange valueRange = sheetsService.spreadsheets().values().get(docId, sheetName).execute();
List<List<Object>> rows = valueRange.getValues();
```

However, this spreadsheet contains formulas and I want the actual formula itself, not the calculated value of the formula.

How do I get the formula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [ValueRenderOptions](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueRenderOption) in your query. This will allow you to get either the calculated value or the raw value.

```
Sheets sheetsService = createSheetsService();
Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.Get request =
    sheetsService.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId, range);
request.setValueRenderOption(valueRenderOption);

ValueRange response = request.execute();
```

Have a look here for some Java examples: [spreadsheets documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)